# Weed eater doesn't cut weeds anymore

Tags: small-engine

I have a curved shaft 25cc 2 stroke Troy-bilt weed eater model #Tb32ec. I was using it to cut down some tall grass and it just quit cutting. It never bogged down or stalled out. I made sure that the string or grass did not get tangled up in the head or neck. The head spins just like it should, and isn't froze up. The motor still runs very strong. What could cause this?

Comment: You may want to provide more information in your question if there is more to it than "tapping the head on the ground" ... I cannot imagine you have not done this already. If there is more to it, please improve your question. I have pretty much the same weed eater which I just purchased about three months ago. It works great without issues. It uses up a lot of line, but other than that, cuts weeds like a big dog.

Comment: I realize the question could have be worded better, and I have cleaned it up some. Not sure it was worth 3 downvotes without comment on why. When new users are guided on what the community expects it makes the site better for everyone. Also it was flagged as being off topic, and while it might be able to be posted on [diy.se] this question is on topic here. Please see the [help/on-topic]`"...even in applications other than automotive so long as the question is related to engine or engine accessories."`

Answer (score 9):

Every time you use them, Periodically **tap the head** on the ground to advance the line. It's important, though, that the head rotates at full speed when you tap it because the centrifugal force of the spinning is what advances the string. Always tap the trimmer head on a soft surface, such as grass, and not on a hard surface, including concrete and wood, or you may damage the trimmer head. It's better to bump the head more often than less often. A blade on the guard automatically cuts the line to the right length.
                              The line of a Weed Eater trimmer head won't advance if it is too short because not enough centrifugal force acts on it. That situation can happen if you don't tap the head often enough or the line becomes sheared by a piece of wire or a root. Running the trimmer with line that is 50 percent or less of the recommended length can cause the head to turn too quickly, which can wear out the engine. A broken spring also can be responsible for failure of the line to advance. The spring can be replaced by removing the spool from the head or by removing the head from the drive shaft, depending on the Weed Eater trimmer model.